# URL rewriting in .NET 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, url-rewriting

I heard that in Visual Studio 2010 give built-in functionality for URL rewriting using its URL Routing engine.

I did URL rewriting in earlier version of visual studio by using plug in like intelligencia urlrewrite.

Can any one explain me or guide me to understand that?

Want to implement dynamic and custom url rewriting in my website.

Comment: I... don't think URL rewriting would be an IDE feature...

Comment: IIS7 has a rewriting module. Is this what you are thinking?

Comment: Both WebForms and MVC support "routing" . Maybe google for that.

Comment: Remember routing which is built into .Net is not the same as rewriting. http://coderjournal.com/2010/03/difference-between-routing-rewriting/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you refering to [.net 4.0 URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) ?

> URL routing was a capability we first
>   introduced with ASP.NET 3.5 SP1, and
>   which is already used within ASP.NET
>   MVC applications to expose clean,
>   SEO-friendly “web 2.0” URLs.  URL
>   routing lets you configure an
>   application to accept request URLs
>   that do not map to physical files.
>   Instead, you can use routing to define
>   URLs that are semantically meaningful
>   to users and that can help with
>   search-engine optimization (SEO).

Comment: Yes, exactly but need more explanation and example.

Comment: Check the link I posteed. Scott Gu has written series of blog posts about it.

Comment: As posted in comment of other answer I actually wrote up a long article on the difference a while back. http://coderjournal.com/2010/03/difference-between-routing-rewriting/ So you got my +1 for correcting this misnomer.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me as well.  I deleted my wrong answer, and thank you for teaching me something new.

Comment: @David .. yeah I know IIS can be used for this but he was asking for VS 2010 so I suspcted that he was talking about .net 4.0 (many get confused with this). :-)