# Forwarding from subdomain to port not working

Tags: apache, subdomain, portforwarding

the problem:

I am running a Windows Vserver and on this server I'm running a standalone Grails app on port 8081, which means that when I open

`localhost:8081 (local)` or `domain:8081`

in the browser, I see the interface of the Grails app.

What I am looking for is a way to type

```
subdomain.domain
```

that forwards me to

```
domain:port
```

I have read that this can be done using a virtual host on Apache. I used the XAMPP Apache because I'm running XAMPP MySQL anyway.
I added this line to the WIndows host file:

```
127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain
```

and this part to apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName http://localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://subdomain.localhost
    Redirect / http://localhost:8081
</VirtualHost>
```

What I expected:

- when I open `domain` I see the xampp admin interface
- when I open `subdomain.domain` I see the Grails app (as `domain:port`)

What happens:

- no matter wheather I open `domain` oder `subdomain.domain` I'm always forwarded to `domain:port`

What am I doing wrong?

Regards
H

Comment: Please read this, I think it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154711/how-can-i-achieve-different-url-start-in-the-same-domain

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. Please note, that I am not looking for wildcard subdomain, but for the combination of a) one specific subdomain and b) no subdomain.

Comment: You can give a wildcard to only a specific subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (no idea where the technical difference is):

```
<VirtualHost Server-IP:80>
    ServerName http://domain
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost Server-IP:80>
    ServerName http://subdomain.domain
    Redirect / http://domain:port
</VirtualHost>
```

I even didn't have to make any entries in the Windows host file. `NameVirtualHost` wasn't necessary either.